# Why I get undefined in last element

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, debugging, random

Why do I get `undefined` in the last element when I distribute the colors in elements?

1. The work of code mixed colors in rows
2. I try to set named colors in the circle without repeating the same color and without being same color of circle

**Problem:** I get `undefined` instead of getting the desired color

```js
let ar = document.getElementsByClassName('row');
let classNameArray = [];
let withoutItem = [],
  arrayWithoutCurrentColor,
  currentColor;
let shuffle = array => {
  let arr = [];
  for (let ii = 0; ii < array.length; ii++) {
    arr.push(array[ii])
  }
  let len = arr.length,
    random, temp;
  while (len > 0) {
    random = Math.floor(Math.random() * len);
    len--;
    temp = arr[len]; // save temp value to don't take new value bcz we change it to random index
    arr[len] = arr[random];
    arr[random] = temp;
  }
  return arr;
}
let search_by_name = (name, array) => {
  let numx;
  array.forEach((el, key) => el == name ? numx = key : '')
  return numx;
};
let remove_item = (name, array) => {
  let array1 = [];
  for (let ii = 0; ii < array.length; ii++) {
    array1.push(array[ii])
  }
  withoutItem = array1;
  withoutItem.splice(search_by_name(name, array1), 1); // remove first element
  console.log("i remove " + name);
  return array1;
}

for (let i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
  // [1] select bg color
  const element = document.getElementsByClassName('row')[i];
  let elelmentClassName = document.getElementsByClassName('row')[i].className;
  let firstClassName = elelmentClassName.split(' ')[1];
  element.style.backgroundColor = firstClassName;

  // [2] add color from class element to array
  classNameArray.push(elelmentClassName.split(' ')[1]); // array with colors

}
// [3] shuffle color arrary
let shuffledArray = shuffle(classNameArray)
for (let indexColor = 0; indexColor < classNameArray.length; indexColor++) { // turn 9
  const element = document.getElementsByClassName('row')[indexColor];
  const color = classNameArray[indexColor];
  // [4] remove same bgcolor 
  arrayWithoutCurrentColor = remove_item(color, shuffledArray);
  currentColor = arrayWithoutCurrentColor[(8 - 1) - indexColor]; // lentgh - 1 for index & (-1) removed element 
  // [5] append name color in element
  element.innerHTML = `<span style="color : ${currentColor}"> ${currentColor} </span>`;
  // [6] remove thee added color to don't repeat same color
  shuffledArray.splice(search_by_name(currentColor, shuffledArray), 1);
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.con {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
}

.row {
  margin: 20px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.row span {
  font-size: 23px;
}
```

```html
<div class="con">
  <div class="row yellow"></div>
  <div class="row red"></div>
  <div class="row black"></div>
</div>
<div class="con">
  <div class="row white"></div>
  <div class="row green"></div>
  <div class="row brown"></div>
</div>
<div class="con">
  <div class="row lightpink"></div>
  <div class="row orange"></div>
  <div class="row orchid"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: `let arr = []; for (let ii = 0; ii < array.length; ii++) { arr.push(array[ii]) }` can be replaced with just `let arr = [...array];`

Comment: Just do some basic debugging.  For example, `console.log(arrayWithoutCurrentColor)` is probably going to reveal your mistake.

Comment: Hello, @Wyck Thank you for this perfect shortcut at the perfect time this is exactly what I needed.
 about the bug. I did exactly what you asked of me, and I knew the cause of the bug, but I was unable to overcome it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify your code to the following:

1. Define a shuffle function
2. Grab all the circle elements
3. Set the background color for all circles, based on their data
4. Shuffle the colors
5. Grab a random color that is not the background, and remove it
6. Apply the color text

**Note:** Do not abuse class names, put the data into a [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes).

```js
const shuffle = (arr) => arr.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);
const remove = (arr, e, amt = 1) => arr.splice(arr.findIndex((x) => x !== e), amt);
const getColor = (el) => el.getAttribute('data-color');

const circles = document.querySelectorAll('.row');

// Set colors
circles.forEach((el) => el.style.backgroundColor = getColor(el));

// Random color
let randColors = shuffle([...circles].map((el) => getColor(el)));

// Apply random color text to circles
circles.forEach((circle) => {
  const [color] = remove(randColors, circle);
  circle.innerHTML = `<span style="color:${color}">${color}</span>`;
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.con {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
}

.row {
  margin: 20px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.row span {
  font-size: 23px;
}
```

```html
<div class="con">
  <div class="row" data-color="yellow"></div>
  <div class="row" data-color="red"></div>
  <div class="row" data-color="black"></div>
</div>
<div class="con">
  <div class="row" data-color="white"></div>
  <div class="row" data-color="green"></div>
  <div class="row" data-color="brown"></div>
</div>
<div class="con">
  <div class="row" data-color="lightpink"></div>
  <div class="row" data-color="orange"></div>
  <div class="row" data-color="orchid"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, @Mr. Polywhirl for everything to editing and organizing my code and big thanks for ur solution.
everything is well but I don't understand 2 points
1 why u use `const [color] ` u don't use `const color `
the second thing the how `shuffle ()`  shuffle  the array